# Basic idea of proof

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

[image]

[image]

I am trying to understand the proof that the expected running time of quicksort is $O(n \log n)$. Could you maybe explain me the basic idea? I am confused right now.

**EDIT**: Suppose that we use the following algorithm:

```
Quicksort(S):
1.  if S contains at most one element then return S
    else
2.       choose an element a randomly from S;
3.       let S1, S2, and S3 be the sequences of elements in S less than, equal to, and greater than a, respectively;
4.       return Quicksort(S1) followed by S2 followed by Quicksort(S3)
```

I have tried the following:

Let $T(n)$ be the expected time required by the Quicksort algorithm in order to sort a sequence of $n$ elements. We have that $T(0)=T(1)=b$ for a constant $b$.

We suppose that the elements $a$ is the $i$-th smallest elements of the $n$ elements of the sequence  $S$.

Then the 2 recursive calls of Quicksort have expected time $T(i-1)$ and $T(n-i)$, respectively.

Since the lines 2-3 require time $O(n)$ and the line 1 requires time  $O(1)$, we have the following recurrence relation:

$$T(n) \leq cn+ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ T(i-1)+T(n-i)\right], n \geq 2$$

$$\\ T(n) \leq cn+ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ T(i-1)+T(n-i)\right] \\ \leq cn+ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ 2T(i-1) \right] =cn+ \frac{2}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} T(i) \\ \Rightarrow T(n) \leq  cn+ \frac{2}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} T(i)(1)$$

We will show that for $n \geq 2$,  $T(n) \leq k n \log n$, for  $k=2(c+b)$ positive.

For $n=2$: From the relation (1) we have  $T(2) \leq c2+ 2b=2(c+b) \checkmark$

We suppose that $T(n) \leq k n \log n$ for some $n \geq 2$.

We will show that $T(n+1) \leq k (n+1) \log (n+1)$ .

From the relation (1) we have $T(n+1) \leq  c(n+1)+ \frac{2}{n+1} \sum_{i=0}^{n} T(i) \leq c(n+1)+ \frac{2}{n+1} (n+1) T(n)= c(n+1)+2T(n) \leq c(n+1)+2  k n \log n \leq (n+1) (c+2k \log n)$

How could we continue? Or should we use strong induction?

Answer (score 1):

The proof revolves around the pivot-selection process. It considers the pivot choices "good" (the ones that divide the data roughly in half) and half "bad" (the ones that end up with a skew more than 3:1), so half of the choices are good and half are bad.

If we're at depth $i$ in the tree, that means we have made $i$ pivots, so we'd expect $i/2$ of them to be good (this is the "Probabilistic Fact" mentioned in the slide). Since each good pivot reduces the data to at most $\frac{3}4n$ (by definition of good), we must have reduced our data set to at most $(\frac{3}4)^{i/2}n$ (simply $i/2$ applications of $3/4$).

Given that, we solve for $1 = (\frac{3}4)^{i/2}n$, to get $i = 2\log_{4/3}(n) = O(\lg n)$ - the expected depth of the leaf nodes. Since each level has to work on the whole array, the amount done at each level is $O(n)$.

Hence total work is just the product of the two: $O(n \lg n)$.

Comment: Could you explain me the following proposition?
$$$$
Since each good pivot reduces the data to at most $\frac{3}4n$ (by definition of good), we must have reduced our data set to at most $(\frac{3}4)^{\frac{i}2}n$.

Comment: A "good" pivot reduces its data to at most three quarters, that's simply what a good pivot does: both $L$ and $G$ have size < $n\frac34$. Since we have $i/2$ such pivots, we reduce the data set by $\frac34$ $i/2$ times.

Comment: I haven't understood why we can say that we must have reduced our data set to at most $\left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^{\frac{i}{2}}n$. If we have bad pivots , don't we reduce the data to quarters?
$$$$
Also could you explain me the following?
$$$$
Since we have $\frac{i}{2}$ such pivots, we reduce the data set by $\frac{3}{4} \frac{i}{2}$ times.

Comment: @evinda A bad pivot could just reduce the data set by one. We're simply ignoring those and assuming that they don't reduce at all.

Comment: I am looking again at the proof.. At which point do we use the probabilistic fact that the expected number of coin tosses required in order to get $k$ heads is $2k$ ?

Comment: @evinda "... so we'd expect $i/2$ of them to be good ..."

Comment: I edited my post. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: @evinda I edited back. You basically just wrote my answer into your question, with slightly different word choice...

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know if it is a complete proof..Anyway... I reedited my post...

Comment: @evinda Now your question starts with one proof of quicksort, and continues with an entirely unrelated proof of quicksort. Also, your recurrence relation is wrong... $T(n) = O(n) + \frac2{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}T(i)$ is $O(n)$.